# Can't render list to div without title, Sencha-Touch 2.0

Tags: sencha-touch-2

**I can't render list without list's title.**

I wasted much time,but I can't find the solution of my problem.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8H48/

And code here:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'myApp',
launch: function() {


    var listdata = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
       fields : ['title'],
       data   : [ {title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'}, {title: 'Charly'} ]
    });


    var test1 = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
       //!!!title: 'Test1',
       itemTpl: '{title}',
       store: listdata
    });


    Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'el',
        height   : '100%',
        items      : [test1],               
    });

}
```

});

**If I remove atributte title, list doesn't render at all.**

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Items within a TabPanel *need* a `title` property to display the name on the tab. If you look in the Web Inspector console, you will see the error message:

```
Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#onFirstItemAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration.
```

Also, you shouldn't use the **renderTo** property. Instead, either add it to Ext.Viewport or set the `fullscreen` configuration to true:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    ...
});
```

Or `fullscreen`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    ...
});
```

You also do not need the `height: 100%` line, as the layout of the components container will handle the item size.

Here is the proper way to do what you want:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'test',
                    xtype: 'list',
                    itemTpl: '{title}',
                    store: {
                        fields : ['title'],
                        data   : [
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Bravo'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Bravo'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'},
                            {title: 'Alpha'}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: does this solution actually address his original question? http://jsfiddle.net/9v2wg/2/, if i remove title property from configuration its still not rendered correctly

Comment: @SaketPatel Thanks, I misread the question and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the ListView but the problem is with TabPanel which was not able to adjust layout according to height of ListView if i remove TabPanel wrapper then the ListView works correctly

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'myApp',
    launch: function() {

        var listdata = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
           fields : ['title'],
           data   : [ {title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'}, {title: 'Bravo'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'}, {title: 'Bravo'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'},{title: 'Alpha'}, {title: 'Bravo'}, {title: 'Charly'} ]
        });

        var test2 = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            // title: 'Test2',
           itemTpl: '{title}',
           store: listdata,
           renderTo: 'el2',
            height   : '100%',
        });
    }
});​​​​​​​
```

If removing the TabPanel is not an option for you then i can try to find out the exact problem, but if it is possible to remove that then you can use this code

Comment: You shouldn't use `renderTo`. Instead, put it inside another component/container.